# IPython: What does AMPL have to point to to run Gecode?

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, ampl

Following this post - http://zverovich.net/2013/06/27/visualizing-geographical-ampl-data-using-ipython-and-google-charts.html

I tried something like this:

```
...
option solver '..\Gecode\include\gecode';
solve;

CreateProcess("..\Gecode\include\gecode.exe") failure!
Error code 2.
```

and running without:

```
"Cannot invoke minos: no such program."
```

After installing gecode on Windows, I don't see a particular file to point to. Does the IPython project need any other AMPL files besides ampl.exe, or is it just missing gecode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to call solve you need to install solvers as well. Normally solver executables are placed on the search path to make them available from AMPL, although you can specify the full path to a solver executable in the solver option, e.g.

```
option solver 'path/to/solver';
```

Several open-source solvers, including gecode, are available for download from the [AMPL Google Code repository](https://code.google.com/p/ampl/downloads/list).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I did try this with gecode but couldn't see an executable in the package. I'll try again with another solver.

Comment: Make sure you download the package for your platform. For example, Windows version is at https://ampl.googlecode.com/files/gecode-4.2.1-20131015-win32.zip and it contains the solver executable (gecode.exe).